# Flex: Filter HierarchicalData child rows

Tags: apache-flex, filter, flex4, flex3, hierarchical-data

I have an `ArrayCollection` of objects used as the source for a `HierarchicalData` object. My object looks roughly like this:

```
ObjectName (String)
SubCollection (ArrayCollection)
```

I am using the `HierarchicalData` in an AdvancedDataGrid to display the data in a grouped format.

I am able to filter the data in the `ArrayCollection` using a `filterFunction`. What I want to do now is also filter the records in the `SubCollection` as well so that only the items that match the filter are displayed in the `AdvancedDataGrid`.

Can anyone tell me how I can filter the child rows in a `HierarchicalData`?

Comment: Recursively loop through it and apply the filterfunction to each subcollection.

Comment: @RIAstar I've tried doing that. During debugging I can see that the `SubCollection` has the correct number of items after being filtered but the `AdvancedDataGrid` still shows the full list of items. Any suggestions?

Comment: Sounds like the view isn't being refreshed after the collection was. `AdvancedDataGrid` can be a royal PITA sometimes (well, most of the time really).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12498719/add-children-to-hierarchicalcollectionview/12534734#12534734) isn't a direct answer to your question, but it should help with some of the background. Essentially I am in the same position as you, where I need to show a specific data set depending on what type of parent node I have.

In this case, starting with an override to `HierarchicalData.getChildren(node:Object):Object` this will give you access to filter the first level children, and will also give you the ability to call a filtered method for sub-children to any n-th level.

You then use your extended class as the source to the ADG.

**A pseudo-code example:**

```
Class MyCollection extends HierarchicalData

override public function getChildren(node:Object):Object 
{
    if (node is a TopLevelObject)
        (node.children as ArrayCollection).filterFunction = filterSub;
        node.children.refresh();
    else if (node is a SubCollectionObject)
        (node.children as ArrayCollection).filterFunction = filterGrandChildren;
        node.children.refresh();

    // - OR -
        //a more complex process of allowing the sub-node to determine it's filter
        return node.filterSubCollectionGrandChildren();


    return node;
}
```

Comment: Mike, you are the MAN! Your answer got me headed in the right direction after many hours of frustration. Thank you.

Comment: One more question if I may. Your answer helped me get the filtering result I wanted, but now I'm running into issues using the `AdvancedDataGrid`s `expandAll()` and `collapseAll()` methods. Have you run into this before?

Comment: issues with? I assume it doesn't open all or close all, briefly looking at this method it's dependent upon a property called 'iterator', which is created in the dataProvider assignment - without going step by step you might need to look at overriding other methods like canHaveChildren() or hasChildren() ? Also in the HierarchicalCollectionView you might need to pay close detail to openNodes. In my app I have a max layer depth of 4 - where I don't explicitly allow a user to expandAll due to the volume of rows - and it's not part of a normal workflow.

Comment: One more thought. dataProviders by nature are not 'live updating' - a refresh() needs to be explicitly called. If you're running a filter on a sub collection that would need to be updated, and from my experience a sub collection is not binding to it's parent (eg editing a sub object) -doesn't trigger a collectionchangeevent to the parent collection. You might need to do something similar to mine where the dataProvider on the grid is refreshed after the filters have "completed".